# bootstrap panel in a table - offset?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a table with 2 rows.  Each row has a bootstrap panel.  The panel looks like it has an offset that moves it up.  Not sure why.  Any ideas?  Am I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonJSFiddle/WEPrP/

```
<table class="right-side" border=2px>
    <tr class="row1">
        <td>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                Summary1
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
        <td>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                Summary2
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap panels have a bottom margin which can cause problems if inserted into a table cell.

Add the following CSS:

```
.panel {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```